# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS only boots with Recovery Mode with Linux 4.7.2 After Upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, dist-upgrade

Upon performing an upgrade from Ubuntu 17 to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, my PC was in standby mode, thereby interrupting the last 1/4 portion of the upgrade. When trying to boot in Grub loader: "Advanced Options"; "Linux 4.7.2", the machine loads the drive and asks for password. Then the screen just goes blank. If I boot into 4.7.2 recovery mode, I am able to access Ubuntu 18.04 and login.

Grub configuration is at `i8042.reset nomodeset`. Previously it was set to `quiet splash.` Neither has solved the boot issue.

What can I do to solve the interrupted upgrade process (to where the upgrade did not successfully complete during running in Ubuntu 17), and to where I can boot into Ubuntu without recovery mode?

System information:

```
~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version: core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Release: 18.04 Codename: bionic

~$ uname -a
4.7.2-040702-generic #201608201334 SMP Sat Aug 20 17:37:03 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is there anything I can do to where Ubuntu 18.04 can boot normally? Without having to choose Recovery Mode? How can I correct this issue?

Comment: I had this same issue in Mint... just upgraded the kernel. Downgrade may work also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following steps in this order:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
# only continue if the above results in zero packages left to configure.
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: this might brak his systems we dont wven know what is going on.

Comment: @vfbsilva Their system is already broken :P Also, dpkg --configure -a is safe. If it works it works. If it doesn't it doesn't. I won't make things worse. HOWEVER dist-upgrade would potentially mess things up if packages are left unconfigured which is why I said don't continue if it doesn't fully configure.